# Never got toll in the mail (NY)

Tags: new-york-city, tolls

Driving home from Maine on June 27th (about one and a half months ago), I passed (briefly) through New York City, and entered Manhattan by the Henry Hudson Bridge. Signs indicated that I would have my license plate photographed and receive a toll bill for $5.50 in the mail. The bill never arrived. Will there be a consequence to not paying the toll if I ever drive through New York again? Is there a way to deal with this online?

EDIT: My car is leased, and the bill went to the leasing company - this possibility (or that it would be relevant at all) did not occur to me because I assumed it would be sent based on the name of the registration rather than the name of the actual owner. I was able to pay the toll by calling in to the number given in the answer.

EDIT2: I eventually received a bill anyway, in October. I could not log in on the tolls by mail website, so I assumed it had cleared itself up. I lost track of the second bill in holiday season chaos, and eventually had to call by phone again to resolve the issue. Fortunately, I had kept the confirmation number from my original payment, but to anyone else in this situation I would recommend *not* attempting as I did to pay over the phone without having received a bill - you will be billed eventually.

Comment: I do not have E-ZPass - I thought this was implied by the fact that I am asking about toll by mail.

Comment: So you paid over the phone and then they sent you a bill? What complete insanity! Might I suggest staying on the Cross Bronx if you have to travel that way again? For you to have hit that particular bridge coming back from Maine, you had to either be on a side trip, lost, or have gotten highly questionable directions from your GPS.

Comment: @MichaelHampton It's on the second choice road route I get via Google Maps, I think it got selected due to traffic that day on the other route

Comment: Curious what would happen to a short stay foreign tourist in an out-of-state (eg. MA) rental car?  Presumably the rental company gets the bill and later charges your credit card the $5.50 plus a hefty "handling fee".

Comment: @Nick it's worse than that. The rental car already has a toll-tag, with a way to disable it that you're not told about.  If you use your own toll-tag, both will scan. If you try to pay cash, it will scan, and the cashier won't want your money.  **If it scans *once***, this signs you up **retroactively for the entire rental period**, though a quick web search shows some consumer protection agency beat them back from the $140 they nicked me (14 day rental) for a single use for a 40 cent toll.

Answer (score 30, accepted):

After crossing the Henry Hudson Bridge without an E-ZPass, you normally should receive a toll bill within 30 days.

However, you might not have received one if the address of your vehicle registration is not your current address, or if the equipment at the toll plaza was malfunctioning when you drove through.

If you didn't receive a toll bill, [you should call 1-800-333-8655](http://www.lohud.com/story/news/traffic/2015/03/12/henry-hudson-bridge-unpaid-cashless-tolls-fees/70198872/). The E-ZPass Customer Service Center can look up any outstanding toll bills you may have by license plate number and [resend the bill to you](https://www.tollsbymailny.com/vector/videotolls/invoices/invoiceInquiry.do?locale=en_US&from=Home). Of course, if they have no record of your crossing the bridge, you don't need to do anything else...

Note that if you don't pay the bill within 30 days after its mailing date, an additional ~ $5 late fee is added to it, and after 60 days [another $50 violation fee](https://www.tollsbymailny.com/en/faq/payments.shtml). The bill can also be [sent to a collection agency](http://nypost.com/2014/03/09/few-honor-cashless-toll-program-at-henry-hudson-bridge/), which could affect your credit rating, so it's a good idea to take care of this quickly.

Answer (score 0):

The bill is not sent to the credit bureaus. I know that, l was in the situation. Lots of vehicles are registered on company names, companies do not have a credit bureau reporting protocol. I was personally told by the collection agency:" we do not report it to credit bureaus".

Comment: I was more concerned about it being reported to my state's DMV (and also possible consequences if I ever go to New York again) than credit bureaus.